# How to change STACK_USE value in coverity tool for C++?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, coverity, coverity-prevent

Coverity is reporting warning for stack size usage of 10k  bytes.
I want to change this value to <25k> bytes.

How can i configure it in coverity ? plz help

Answer (score 1):

Need to specify certain command line options.

> **./cov-analyze** --dir `../tmp/cov` -all --checker-option
>   STACK_USE:max_single_base_use_bytes:`<your_stack_size_in_bytes>` --checker-option
>   STACK_USE:max_total_use_bytes:`<your_stack_size_in_bytes>`

`../tmp/cov` - directory which contains output from **./cov-build**